# Do the ceremonial rental agreements for Eruv's expire?

Tags: eruv-chatzerot

Aside from the [terms to create an Eruv](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/130822/2504), how long are these ceremonial lease's valid for?

- When someone sells a house inside of an Eruv, must they get permission from the new owner or otherwise renew the lease for the Eruv?
- Do they have to have set terms? Or, does a lease last forever?

Comment: Usually there's a very long term (99 years, 25 years) but indefinite leases are also valid so long as there's no ownership change (which may include a local election)

Comment: Oh really that's very interesting, so when a local election happens if the mayor changes they have to redo the lease? That would make sense? Can you answer with that data point and cite where I can find more info about it?